# How to move my top navigation bar to the right side of the screen?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

My top navigation bar is on the left side of the screen, how do I move it to the right? The current output is the top navigation bar appearing on the left side of the screen. The wanted output is the top navigation appearing on the right side of the screen.
I have tried using

```
.li {
    float:right
    }
```

However this does not move my top navigation bar to the right side of the screen. My code is attached below.

This is my dynamic.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    </head>
    @component('layouts.components.navbar')
    @endcomponent
    @if ($pageContent->URI == 'shop')
            @component('layouts.components.sidenavbar')
            @endcomponent
        @endif
    <body>
        {!!$pageContent->pageContent!!}
        @if ($pageContent->URI == 'shop')
            @component('layouts.components.shop')
            @endcomponent
        @endif
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-
```

DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"

This is my navbar.blade.php:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Marketing 4 Growth</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            @foreach($navContent as $nav)
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{!!$nav->navLink!!}">{!!$nav->navName!!}</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is my style.css:

```
.margin-top-20 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.feature-img {
    max-height: 200px;
}

.li {
    float: right;
}
```

Thanks for spending your time to try read this question and help me! :D

Comment: can you add some code snippet showing the exact problem you described? That will be little more helpful.

Comment: Debsmita Paul, how do I add that?

Comment: This is blade templates. It will be good if you can show us the final HTML and CSS. For example, in jsfiddle or here in Code snippet.

Comment: I don't know what Code snippet or jsfiddle is, I am new to programming.

Comment: Google is your friend. Just try a little before you ask. Just try to put new terms like `Code snippet` or `jsfiddle` there and you can save everyone's time.

Comment: And just as an additional tip, try to reduce your code before posting it. There's a lot of code in your question that is not related. As a good practice is to make it with just the bits that are related to the problem. Most often than not in the process of simplifying you example you will find the problem.